# How to parse a log string in Logstash using Grok?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to parse the following string using Grok;

```
2018-06-08 13:26:02.002851: <action cmd="run" options="IGNORE_ERROR" path="/usr/lib/vmware/likewise/bin/lw-lsa get-metrics"> (/etc/vmware/vm-support/ad.mfx) took 0.000 sec
```

I want to separate the above out into columns ultimately like `TIMESTAMP, ACTION, OPTIONS, PATH` etc - I have tried multiple combinations but have so far failed.

Comment: You should be able to try and finally solve it using the grok debugger here: https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grok pattern for above log:->

`%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}:%{SPACE}\<%{WORD:action}%{SPACE} %{DATA:kvpairs}\>%{SPACE}\(%{DATA:path_2}\)%{SPACE}took%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:time_taken}%{SPACE}%{WORD:time_unit}`

In the above grok pattern, I have captured `cmd`, `options` and `path` in an event named kvpairs. This is because these key-value pairs can be easily extracted in logstash using `kv` filter.  So your filter configuration will look like:->

```
filter{
    grok(
        match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}:%{SPACE}\<%{WORD:action}%{SPACE} %{DATA:kvpairs}\>%{SPACE}\(%{DATA:path_2}\)%{SPACE}took%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:time_taken}%{SPACE}%{WORD:time_unit}"}
    )

    kv{
        source => "kvpairs"
    }

    date{
        match => ["timestamp","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
    }
}
```

`kv` filter by default takes space as the delimiter and will extract columns `cmd`,`options` and `path`.
`date` filter will make the `@timestamp` variable.